Выдаваемая ipef3 пропускная способность намного меньше реальной
Есть две виртуальные машины на базе VMworkstation. Они находятся в одной сети VMnet19 и обе машины имеют следующие настройки:

Я запускаю одну из машин как сервер:
iperf3 -s
А вторую как клиент, ставя время тестирования 30 секунд.
iperf3 -c 192.168.0.1 -t 30
И получаю такой вот результат:

Почему получается такой результат, а не 5 Mbits/s? Так и должно быть? Если да, то почему, а если нет, то где я ошибся?

А если поставить 1000, получится 1 Mbits/sec?

Уберите packet loss, получите полосу куда лучше. retransmit на такой большой латентности в 10мс - это ожидаемо больно на одном потоке TCP (а без доп ключей iperf3 делает именно TCP коннект).

На случай, если кто-то в поиске решения проблемы попадет сюда. Мелкий был прав. Оставил в настройках сетевой карты Workstation только ограничение в 5 Mbit/s. Задержку и потерю пакетов задал, используя на одной из машин утилиту tc. Все начало работать намного стабильнее. Очень хорошо написано про неё здесь:
https://netbeez.net/blog/how-to-use-the-linux-traffic-control/
